# How to save a Decodable.Protocol object to a variable?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, decodable

In my application, several controllers have a very similar code structure. The differences are minimal. So for optimization I decided to create a basis for these controllers and inherit each specific controller from the basis.

I have a function for sending network requests and processing a response. I pass the response structure as a parameter to this function so that the function returns a ready-made response structure to me. Each such structure is `Decodable`.

An example of such a structure:

```
struct APIAnswerUserActivity: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let code: Int?
    let data: [UserActivity]?
    let total: Int?
}
```

Function for network requests, an object (structure) of the `Decodable.Protocol` type is accepted as a `jsonType` parameter:

```
public func networkRequest<T: Decodable> (
    url: String,
    timeout: Double = 30,
    method: URLMethods = .GET,
    data: [String : String]? = nil,
    files: [URL]? = nil,
    jsonType: T.Type,
    success: @escaping (T) -> Void,
    failure: @escaping (APIError) -> Void
) -> URLSessionDataTask { ... }
```

There are several parameters in the main controller that I override through override in the child controllers. One of these parameters should be an object of type `Decodable` for the general function to receive data correctly. The JSON structures of the response are very similar, but still slightly different. A common structure for them cannot be created because the data is still a little different.

If in the main controller do this:

```
public var decodableType: Decodable.Type {
    return APIAnswerUserActivity.self
}
```

That will work, and it is possible to redefine types, but the network function does not accept this. It needs the `Decodable.Protocol` object. If the type `decodable.Protocol` is specified for the variable `decodableType`, then it is no longer possible to add `APIAnswerUserActivity.self`, which is quietly accepted when the networkRequest function is called.

How to be in this situation? I hope that I managed to correctly and clearly state the essence of my problem.

Comment: "several controllers have a very similar code structure, the differences are minimal, so for optimization I decided to create a basis for these controllers, and inherit each specific controller from the basis."  What are the things that you call 'controllers'?

Comment: @ElTomato, I have UserActivityTableViewController, UserInvoicesTableViewController etc. In these controllers, the method of infinite scrolling is used with loading data from the network when reaching the end of the table. I create InfinityScrollTableViewController and moved all common logic on this controller. On create UserActivity controller I do: class UserActivityTableViewController: InfinityScrollTableViewController { ... }

Comment: Why don't you just subclass UIViewController or UITableViewController?

Comment: @ElTomato all UITableViewControllers have 90% similarity, the differences are minimal. I think it’s worth making all the similarities in 1 controller, and inherit each specific controller from it and redefine only the necessary methods.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code represented by the ellipses ({ ... }) in the partial source above (the code that builds the URLSessionDataTask). This is probably where the problem is. Can you please include it?

Comment: @iamtimmo,I have a getElementsFromNetwork method in InfinityScrollTableViewController, this method runs the networkRequest method (I left its code above). Since the networkRequest method requires the Decodable type as a required parameter, it must be passed. I tried to create public var as type Decodable.Protocol in InfinityScrollTableViewController and override this in subsidiary TableViewController, but i get compile error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Владислав Артемьев, I'm still not sure that I completely understand the problem because you haven't shared the code that takes the `Decodable` class. But the issues seems to be about how to pass a `Decodable` class.

I hope the following can help clarify how you can impose the right constraint on the generic and how you should declare the variable. You can paste it into a playground and experiment.

```swift
import Foundation

struct FakeToDo: Decodable {
    var userId: Int
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var completed: Bool
}

enum URLMethods {
    case GET
    case POST
}

func networkRequest<T: Decodable> (
    url: String,
    timeout: Double = 30,
    method: URLMethods = .GET,
    data: [String : String]? = nil,
    files: [URL]? = nil,
    jsonType: T.Type,
    success: @escaping (T) -> Void,
    failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void
) -> URLSessionDataTask {

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            failure(error!)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let value = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else { return }

        // get back on the main queue for UI
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            success(value)
        }
    })
    return task
}

class Example<T> where T: Decodable {
    let type: T.Type

    init(_ type: T.Type) {
        self.type = type
    }

    public var decodableType: T.Type {
        return type
    }
}

let decodableType = Example(FakeToDo.self).decodableType

let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
let task = networkRequest(url: url, jsonType: decodableType,
                          success: { value in print(value) },
                          failure: { error in print(error) })

task.resume()
```

Comment: How I can override this var? In InfiniteScrollTableViewController I create function getElementsFromNetwork, this function get data from API. I create UserActivityTableViewController: InfiniteScrollTableViewController and UserInvoicesTableViewController: InfiniteScrollTableViewController. In InfiniteScrollTableViewController I create public var decodableType and I want override this var in UserActivityTableViewController and UserInvoicesTableViewController. Function getElementsFromNetwork running into InfiniteScrollTableViewController.

Comment: Please create a new question for this.